# Print: png or pdf? Size?

Tags: print-design, color-spaces, paper-size

I am sure this question has been asked many times but I can't find it, here it is: 
I am exporting from photoshop an image, 300dpi, I had set the image size at 2480x3508 px thinking it was A4, but the copy shop said that is A3, who is right here?

What size do I have to set please to have the image 300dpi A4?

Another thing: when I transport from png or jpeg to pdf for printing, the colors change and become darker - I set the png for CMYK colors, what can I do to keep the same colors? Should I ask the copy shop to print the png? They specifically asked for pdf (maybe I should find another copy shop :D) Thank you... as you can see I am learning

Comment: There is no such thing  as a  CMYK PNG  file, its  allways RGB. if the values you gave are correct  then its a bit  bigger  than a a4 anyway print is likely  right  about  yoir metadata info.

Comment: it may depend on exactly what you're trying to print 'graphics' or 'photography'. For 'photography' I once spent a year [&  lot of money] trying to find a print shop who could send back what I thought I'd sent them - I used their printer profiles specific to their machine & material [£300/m² canvas], calibrated my workflow to within an inch of its life, no joy on CMYK at all. I eventually found one I can send sRGB JPGs to & they always give me a damn good approximation of what I 'think I saw'. [downside is I can't get that fantastic canvas from them]. To this day I don't actually know why.

Answer (score 1):

A3 is 11.69" x 16.54" inches

2480px/300dpi = 8.26"

3580px/300dpi = 11.93"

A4 is 8.27" x 11.69" (2481px x 3507px at 300dpi)

So the answer is neither, but it's closer to A4. Definitely not A3.

You can't have a CMYK PNG.  The format only supports RGB or Indexed colour. Some RGB colours are out of the CMYK colour gamut, and these can't be printed. Without seeing the image, I can't tell if some parts are out of gamut.

Comment: thank you!! so what format should i use to get CMYK colors that the printer can read? I am making a product that people can download and print on their own, should it then be just jpeg to make things easier? How can I get a bit more control about the colors, to make sure everyone has more or less the same results? Thank you very much

Comment: If it's for home inkjet printing, then most of these consumer grade printers don't support CMYK files. You will just need to choose colours which are not out of gamut.  PNGs aren't suitable for print really. They're a web format. Do what your copy shop suggested. Give them a PDF instead.